# Delete item from 2D list

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization

I have a 2D list in python declared this way:

```
the_list = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

It produces the following list:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I then edit the list by replacing the 0s with 1s and 2s. I am sure there is never going to be more than one of these values in the list at once.

What is the fastest way to delete (i.e. replace 0) an element in the list by value?
I've been using this so far:

```
def deleteIntFromArray(array, int_to_delete):
    for i in array:
        if int_to_delete in i:
            for j in range(0, len(i)):
                if i[j] == int_to_delete:
                    i[j] = 0
```

Comment: `if int_to_delete in i:` is unnecessary and requires iterating through `i`.  It might also be better to use `enumerate` in the second `for` loop instead of `range`

Comment: You don't mention, how large your arrays are. You can speed up large array creation and substitions by using `NumPy`. Create an array with `arr=numpy.zeros((i,j))` and change all values m to n with a command like `np.place(arr, arr == m,  n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have this list:

```
l = [[1,0,0], [0,4,0], [0,0,1], [3,0,0]]
```

You can delete (say) the 1's using a list comprehension instead:

```
l = [[0 if x == 1 else x for x in sub_l] for sub_l in l]

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I keep forgetting how useful list comprehension can be

Comment: @GiorgioCavicchioli I mean, you could also just do the same in a for-loop... the crux of the matter is you should check equality with your target as you iterate, and `if int_to_delete in i:` is totally redundant!

Answer (score 2):

I think without this line your code would execute in less time.

```
if int_to_delete in i:
```

Because the membership function (in) will be basically compare every element in list and if the given number is member then again you are performing check in the following for loop.

Comment: Agree, I was thinking that it was useless to iterate over thew sublist if the item wasn't there somewhere. But I forgot `in` iterates over it anyway. This is when I realise I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to accomplish this:

```
the_list = [[3, 7, 8], [6, 6, 2], [7, 10, 9]]

def drop_int(arr, i):
    '''
    arr : 2d list
    i : integer to replace with 0
    '''
    return [[0 if c==i else c for c in row] for row in arr]

drop_int(the_list, 7)
# returns:
[[3, 0, 8], [6, 6, 2], [0, 10, 9]]

drop_int(the_list, 6)
# returns:
[[3, 7, 8], [0, 0, 2], [7, 10, 9]]
```

Here is a version that edits the list in-place rather than returning building a new list.

```
def drop_int_inplace(arr, i):
    for row in arr:
        for j,c in enumerate(row):
            if c==i:
                row[j] = 0
    return arr
```

---

They appear to be about the same for the algorithms as they are coded (within 10%).  Quick tests of efficiency:

#### 5000 x 5000 list

```
import random

the_list = [[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(5000)] for j in range(5000)]

%%timeit
i = random.randint(0,10)
drop_int(the_list,i)
# prints:
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop

%%timeit
i = random.randint(0,10)
drop_int_inplace(the_list,i)
# prints:
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.2 s per loop
```

#### 500 x 500 list

```
the_list = [[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]

%%timeit
i = random.randint(0,10)
drop_int(the_list,i)
# prints:
# 100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop

%%timeit
i = random.randint(0,10)
drop_int_inplace(the_list,i)
# prints:
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have trouble believing that building a new list is going to be faster than modifying one in-place